# Drawing Images on Canvas Using Node.js and EJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, canvas, ejs

So, I'm new to Node and building a practice website where a user can sign in and create a chatroom anywhere on a campus map or join an existing chat room.  I've got my Mongo schema etc working.  Just having a little trouble rendering my models the way I want to.

Basically, I'm trying to use canvas to first draw the map and then draw location pointers for all the existing chatrooms.

Here's my controller:

```
var db = require('../models')

module.exports = function(req, res) {
// finds all the current chatrooms and passes them to the
// the campus map to be rendered
db.Chatroom.find().exec(function(err, chatrooms) {
    if (err) throw err;

    res.render('map.ejs', { title: "Campus Map", chatrooms : chatrooms })
});
};
```

And here's my view:

```
<% include header.ejs %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var images = {};

    /*
    Pre-loads the images so they can be drawn in order.
    */
    function loadImages() {
        var sources = ["campus_map.png", "icon.png"]
        var loadedImages = 0;

        for (var src in sources) {
            images[src] = new Image();
            images[src].onload = function() {
                if(++loadedImages >= 2) {
                    drawImages();
                }
            };
            images[src].src = sources[src];
        }
    }

    /*
    Draws the map and all the current chatroom locations onto the canvas.
    */
    function drawImages() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

        ctx.drawImage(images[0], 0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        chatrooms.forEach(function(chatroom) { 
        ctx.drawImage(images[1], chatroom.x_coordinate + 10, chatroom.y_coordinate + 20, 20, 20);
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="loadImages();">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<% include footer.ejs %>
```

I think my issue is that I'm trying to access the context passed to the view by my controller (chatrooms) in a script block in my head, but I don't really know how to get around this.

Any guidance would be much appreciated!  Thanks.